# Avoiding multiple `or` expressions

Tags: oracle, query-refactor

I have the following oracle SQL and its works and all but it's quite ugly with all of the `or`s. Is there a more concise way of doing this?

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE
  (SUBJECT ='STAT' and TERM ='111') or  
  (SUBJECT ='STAT' and TERM ='222') or  
  (SUBJECT ='ENGLISH' and TERM ='555') or 
  (SUBJECT ='COMM' and TERM ='444') or
  (SUBJECT ='COMM' and TERM ='333') or  
  (SUBJECT ='STAT' and TERM ='666')
  ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might prefer something like this:

```
select *
from foobar
where (subject,term) in ( ('STAT','111')
                         ,('STAT','222')
                         ,('ENGLISH','555')
                         ,('COMM','444')
                         ,('COMM','333')
                         ,('STAT','222')
                         ,('STAT','666') 
                        );
```

DBFiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be25ec44b846b63e5a68159626c19329)

Comment: I wish MS SQL Server had this syntax.

Comment: @RossPresser I think there is a Connect item/suggestion for the syntax to be added. You can vote ;)

Comment: I found that there *is* something roughly as capable: `SELECT * FROM foobar INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('4','a'),('5','b')) AS myTable(subject,term)) ON myTable.subject=foobar.table and mytable.term=foobar.term`

Comment: but I would like this actual syntax. Any idea where the Connect item is?

Comment: @RossPresser here it is: [Add support for ANSI standard row value constructors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors) The answer from MS was: *"Hello. Thank you for your feedback. We're certainly considering row value constructors for a future release of SQL Server."* At least the request is still open, 10 years now.

Comment: @RossPresser see also my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/selecting-where-two-columns-are-in-a-set/34270#34270 Your join solution can be simplified a bit for SQL Server.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ...and [here's the azure feedback port of that connect item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894992-add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructo) 

Comment: @PeterVandivier yeah, it's sad. *"We’re certainly considering row value constructors for a future release of SQL Server."* (12 years ago)

Answer (score 11):

In terms of a pure code cleansing, the following looks cleaner:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM foobar 
  WHERE (SUBJECT = 'STAT' and TERM IN ('111','222','666') )
    OR  (SUBJECT = 'COMM' and TERM IN ('333','444') )
    OR  (SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH' and TERM = '555' ) ;
```

Depending on the application and how often the logic will be reused, it may also be worth setting up a lookup table to apply the logic:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar_lookup (SUBJECT VARCHAR2(7), TERM VARCHAR2(3)) ;

INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'STAT',    '111' FROM dual ;
INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'STAT',    '222' FROM dual ;
INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'STAT',    '666' FROM dual ;
INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'COMM',    '444' FROM dual ;
INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'COMM',    '333' FROM dual ;
INSERT INTO foobar_lookup SELECT 'ENGLISH', '555' FROM dual ;

SELECT f.* FROM foobar f
JOIN foobar_lookup fl 
    ON fl.subject = f.subject
    AND fl.term = f.term ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it. Using the where (col1,col2) might cause Oracle to not use any indexes, but this looks like a table to the query, so it might work better. You will know once you test the various versions.

```
  WITH subject_terms 
            (subject,   term) AS
    ( SELECT 'STAT'   , '111' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'STAT'   , '222' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ENGLISH', '555' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'COMM'   , '444' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'COMM'   , '333' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'STAT'   , '666' FROM dual )
SELECT * 
  FROM foobar             fb
 INNER JOIN subject_terms st
    ON fb.subject = st.subject
   AND fb.term    = st.term;
```

DBFiddle [Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24f6c1b9830948805df490465bcc6ffc)